# ¿Cómo comprimir varios documentos en WebForm?

Tags: webforms

Estoy haciendo un sistema en donde un profesor podrá generar varios certificados (son PDF) dependiendo de las personas que hayan asistido. Cuando le de click al botón generar certificados, le debe aparecer que se va a descargar un zip con todos los archivos PDF. Pero al momento de ejecutar me aparece este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Muestro esto en caso de que NO salga la imagen con el error**

```
    Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
No se admite el formato proporcionado de la ruta de acceso.
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código. 

Detalles de la excepción: System.NotSupportedException: No se admite el formato proporcionado de la ruta de acceso.

Error de código fuente: 


Línea 60:                 foreach (var x in list_temp)
Línea 61:                 {
Línea 62:                     zip.AddFile(x.FileName);
Línea 63:                 }
Línea 64: 

Archivo de origen: C:\Users\gpoma\3D Objects\wsCharlas\wsCharlas\wsCharlas\Reportes\wPrueba.aspx.cs    Línea: 62 

Seguimiento de la pila: 


[NotSupportedException: No se admite el formato proporcionado de la ruta de acceso.]
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath) +12767947
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath) +118
   System.IO.File.InternalGetLastWriteTimeUtc(String path, Boolean checkHost) +51
   Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Create(String nameInArchive, ZipEntrySource source, Object arg1, Object arg2) +446
   Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.AddFile(String fileName, String directoryPathInArchive) +36
   Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.AddFile(String fileName) +7
   wsCharlas.Reportes.wPrueba.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\gpoma\3D Objects\wsCharlas\wsCharlas\wsCharlas\Reportes\wPrueba.aspx.cs:62
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
```

Estoy usando la libreria `using Ionic.Zip;`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /**********IGNOREN ESTA PARTE**********/
        string ID = Request.QueryString["x"];

        ID = ID.Replace("°", "/");
        ID = ID.Replace("¬", "+");

        ClsEncripta Encrip = new ClsEncripta();

        string[] Result = Encrip.Desencriptar(ID).Split('|');
        /**************************************/

        List<ReportDocument> list_temp = new List<ReportDocument>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= Result.Length -1; i++)
        {
            DataTable dtInteresado = new DataTable();
            dtInteresado = TablaInteresadoIndividual(obtenerInteresado(Result[0], Result[i]));

            ReportDocument Reporte = new ReportDocument();
            Reporte.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/"), "ReporteInscritos.rpt"));

            Reporte.SetDataSource(dtInteresado);
            crvReporteParametro.ReportSource = Reporte;

            list_temp.Add(Reporte);

            //Reporte.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "Reporte");
        }

        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
            foreach (var x in list_temp)
            {
                zip.AddFile(x.FileName);
            }

            Response.Clear();
            Response.BufferOutput = false;
            string zipName = String.Format("Zip_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Si mi operación esta mal y hay otra forma de realizarlo, por favor, les estaría muy agradecido si me lo comparten.

Comment: El error **siempre** debe ir como texto, no como imagen. Para las rutas de archivos, no se usa la barra \?? ese programa parece estar usando otra barra...

Comment: Hola amigo @gbianchi, lo que hago es generar varios pdf y almacenarlos en el zip, asi lo encontre en este blog "https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/286/downloading-multiple-files-in-asp-net"

Comment: Por eso no le puse dirección, o te refieres a la direcciones en donde se tiene que descargar?

Comment: el error te dice que x.FileName no es una ruta valida. Son rutas validas?

Comment: La dirección esta en la lista "list_temp"

Comment: Pero cuando lo coloco me marca con error.

Comment: cuando colocas que cosa? te dice que es una ruta invalida. Nos puedes mostrar como estan esas rutas?

Comment: a ya, solo admite rutas, pensaba que tambien podia admitir reportes

Comment: Te explico, quiero comprimir reportes pdf que realizo con crystal report. Cuando se presione un boton, estos reportes son generados, y quiero que todos esos reportes que lo estoy almacenando en la lista "List<ReportDocument> list_temp = new List<ReportDocument>();" se comprima. Pero estos documentos no tienen ruta, ya que son generados y guardados en esa lista. ¿Qué tendría que hacer en ese caso amigo @gbianchi?

Comment: y esos reportes pdf, los guardas en el disco en algun lado? si esa libreria zipfile trabaja como trabajan todas, comprime archivos, no objetos en memoria ;)

Comment: Se tiene que guardar en el disco dependiendo en donde lo quiera guardar el usuario.

Comment: Exacto!!! objetos en memoria, y que pena con lo de zipfiel, pensé que me podría ayudar con esa operación jeje.